# Laravel 5 - Unable to access the ID variable within the route

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

My current setup:

**Controller:**

```
public function showGeneralPage($id, ShowClinicFormRequest $request)
{
    return View::make('clinic.general', ['clinic' => Clinic::where('id', $id)
        ->first()]);
}
```

**ShowClinicFormRequest:**

```
public function authorize()
{
    $clinicId = $this->route('clinic');

    return Clinic::where('id', $clinicId)
    ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->exists();
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('clinic/{id}/general', 'ClinicController@showGeneralPage
```

When trying to click through to the page - `<a href="{{ url('/clinic/general') }}">General</a>`, it presents a `forbidden` error.

To be honest, I'm not overly fussed on even having to show the ID based on the clinic, within the URL, but I can't see any other way around it? Any help would be hugely appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: The URL you're generating doesn't have an ID value in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this (I've found three problems tho):

```php
$id = $this->route()->parameter('id'); // $this->route('id') works as well
```

Also you need to pass the `id` when generating the `URI`, for example:

```php
{{ url("clinic/{$id}/general") }} // $id may have some value, i.e: 10
```

Also, you need to change the order of parameters here:

```php
 public function showGeneralPage($id, ShowClinicFormRequest $request)
```

Should be:

```php
 public function showGeneralPage(ShowClinicFormRequest $request, $id)
```

---

*Note: When using `Method Injection` place your method parameters after the type hinted dependency injection parameters.*

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here. First, you have to pass the id along when generating the URL. Assuming a variable `$id`:

```
url('clinic/'.$id.'/general')
```

Second, you are trying to retrieve the parameter `clinic`, however it is actually called `id`.
Change it to:

```
$clinicId = $this->route('id');
```